# Discord bot can't read commands

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I've been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRHUW_KnHLs on how to create a discord bot, and it dosn't recognize my commands.
This is my main code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os 

from help_cog import help_cog
from music_cog import music_cog

# Command prefix
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is up and ready!")

bot.remove_command("help")

bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))
bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))    

# Run the client
with open('token.txt', 'r') as file:
    token = file.readlines()[0]
bot.run(token)
```

Here is my music_cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 - reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnected_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None
    
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))

    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception:
                return False
        return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}

    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegAudio(m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True
            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['sorce']

            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc == await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel :-(")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(m_url, ** self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    # Play music command
    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p", "playing"], help="Play a song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format, try a different keyword")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_musci(ctx)
    
    # Pause music command
    @commands.command(name="pause", aliases=["stop", "paused"], help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_pause:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()
    
    # Resume music command
    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r", "unpause"], help="Resumes playing the current song")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    # Skip music command
    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the currently played song")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)

    # Queue command
    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays all the songs currently in the queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx, *args):
        retval = ""

        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if i > 4: break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + '\n'

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in the queue.")
    
    # Clear command
    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the current song and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    # Leave command
    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["disconnect", "l", "d"], help="Kick the bot from the voice channel")
    async def leave(self, ctx, *args):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()
```

Here is my help_cog:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class help_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        self.help_message = """
```

General commands:
!help - Displays all the avaiable commands
!p  - Finds the song on youtube and plays it in yout current channel. Will resume playing the current song if it was paused
!q - Displays the current music queue
!skip - Skips the current song being played
!clear - Stops the music and clears the queue
!leave - Disconnects the bot from the voice channel
!pause - Pauses the current song being played or resumes if already paused
!resume - Resumes playing the current song

```
"""

        self.text_channel_text = []

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(help_cog(bot))

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        for guild in self.bot.guilds:
            for channel in guild.text_channels:
                self.text_channel_text.append(channel)

        await self.send_to_all(self.help_message)

    async def send_to_all(self,msg):
        for text_channel in self.text_channel_text:
            await text_channel.send(msg)

    # Help command
    @commands.command(name='help', help="Displays all the avaiable commands")
    async def help(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.help_message)
```

I've tried many things such as paths, trying to load the cogs in a different way. I can't seem to find the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Following your code, many updates that occurred in [Version 2.0](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html?highlight=version) contain lots of updates on how to start, refresh, and save cog files. Let me show you around.

In a cog adding process you will need to set the loading function then your defined variables then finally the setup **asyncio** function. a prime example of how a basic cog file would look like is as the following:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class basic(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client): 
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def hi(self, ctx):
      await ctx.reply("Hello there!")


async def setup(client): 
  await client.add_cog(basic(client))
```

now it's important to add this cog file in your main.py file along with your on_ready event. It would look something like this:

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", intents=intents
)
client.remove_command("help")


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Activity(
            type=discord.ActivityType.playing, name=f"with {len(client.guilds)} servers and {len(client.users)} members"))
  
    await client.load_extension("cogs.basic")
```

> **This should be working with you properly, if any issue occurs feel free to comment to this post and let me assist you with further aid. Please don't forget to refer back to the [API](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) as it contains so much good to know!**

Comment: Don't load extensions in `on_ready`, it fires multiple times. Cogs should be loaded in `setup_hook`. Also, don't change presence (or make any API calls for that matter) in `on_ready`. Docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/migrating.html#extension-and-cog-loading-unloading-is-now-asynchronous